# Facebook API - All Mutual Friends returning error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

Trying to get my head around it but getting the same error.
I have created 3 test users(user1,user2,user3) and each have added each other as friends.

Now I want to test the facebook API for all mutual friends by sending the below data :-

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/**[user2_userID]**/all_mutual_friends?access_token=**[User1_access_token]**&appsecret_proof=**[app_secret_proof_created_by_hashing_token_and_app_secret]**

This is to get the mutual friends between user1 and user2 but I get the below error :-

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (all_mutual_friends) on node type (User)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AlCoK/9o/6h"
  }
}
```

I even tried with actual users thinking the test users might have some issues but I get the same error.
Can someone tell me what exactly wrong am I doing here? The document says the same.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/all_mutual_friends

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for `mutual_friends`

```
{user-id}?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)
```

for `all_mutual_friends`

```
{user-id}?fields=context.fields(all_mutual_friends.limit(100))
```

**Permissions**

- A valid user access token with user_friends permission is required to
  view the mutual friends of other friends using the app.
- The user in the request and the session user must both have granted
  user_friends permission to the app.
- The ID will be returned for a mutual friend only if the given user
  has installed your app and granted the user_friends permission
- If you want to call this endpoint on behalf two app-users who are not
  friends, then you must provide the appsecret_proof parameter along
  with the user access token when making the request. This means you
  must call this endpoint from your server.
- Usage of the this field requires review by Facebook before it can be
  used by in production by non-developers of your app.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change the URL to get the results. The FB documents do not give much information. I used :-

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1234567890?fields=context.fields(all_mutual_friends.limit(100))&access_token={token}&appsecret_proof={app_secret}